# E2E tests and fan in build pipeline

Tags: testing, microservices

In chapter 9 (Testing) of the book Building microservices (2nd edition)

Author suggests using a Fan-in approach to have a single shared E2E tests for all microservices. This way tests of unchanged services doesn't have to run again and make the whole process faster.

[image]

Question is,

Lets assume "Web shop" service is running its build pipeline and its currently at the "End-to-end tests" step.

What would happen if "Customer service" starts its build parallelly?

Would "End-to-end tests" step of "Web shop" be skipped and wait for "Customer service" to finish?

I wanted to understand how this would work out in real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would happen if "Customer service" starts its build parallelly?

Nothing special. E2E build will enqueue another trigger from upstream.

> Would "End-to-end tests" step of "Web shop" be skipped and wait for "Customer service" to finish?

Really depends on the CI server & tools in use. As new triggers for the E2E build queue up (because something is always building upstream on a busy day), the CI server here may "skip to the latest queued trigger" to save resources and time.

> I wanted to understand how this would work out in real world.

The diagram is way too simplified. It depict an "ideal" flow where changes just flow through the beautiful CI-CD pipes and integrate without a hitch.

Real world project usually are more complicated. There are different version, feature and hot-fix branches of the components involved. This are complex dependencies between these branches and versions. There might be more than one build flows involved, for different variations of the product, feature wise or distribution wise.